# Query Excel array by time

Tags: arrays, excel

I have an array that starts at 9am (9) and goes to 4pm (16) based on 24 hour time format.  Depending on the current time (I query Excel for the current hour) I want to look back 1,2,3,4 hours etc.  Obviously if it's 4pm (16) then going back is easy, but if it is 9am I want to go to the 4pm, 3pm,2pm etc. from the previous day (higher value in the array 16,15,14 etc.).  Array is set up like this:

```
9 100
10 110
11 50
12 200
13 250
14 10
15 150
16 130
```

For example, if I want it to look back 2 hours, at 4pm (16) minus 2pm (14) would be 130-10=120.  For 9am minus 3pm the previous day (15) would be 100-150=-50.

There's probably some logic with difference or algebra that I'm not getting.  I've thought about index() but that could get tricky.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include an example maybe with a screen shot or a clearer explanation for what you're looking for? I understand the foundation of basically needing a loop lookup, but how are lookign to apply it? A formula? A table? Have you researched using `mod`?

Comment: Added example, see above

Comment: You say "*For 9am minus 3pm the previous day (15) would be 100-150=-50.*", but we can't see the previous day's data for 3pm. Yet you state that it is 150. Why? Is the data for each day identical?

Comment: The data updates on the hour, so row 15 would be yesterday's 3pm until today's update.  Do you see row 15 = 150?  That is yesterday's data assuming we are at 9am right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to make some assumptions about your question. I assume that by *array*, you mean a range of cells, say A1:B8,  containing the values you listed. If that's the case then the task could be solved fairly trivially using the modulo operator (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Step 1 would be make the hour subtraction and apply the `Mod()` function, like so:

```
=MOD(ReferenceTime-FirstHourInList-HourReduction,HoursListCount)
```

In the 9 - 2 example, you gave `=MOD(9-9-2,8)` yields 6, the item at index 6 in your list being 15.

Step 2 would simply be the subtractions of the two look up values, using `INDEX()`, remembering that the function is 1-based.

If you had a worksheet that looked as below:

[image]

then the formula in cell B3 would simply be:

```
=INDEX($B$6:$B$13,MOD($B$1-9-$B$2,8)+1)-INDEX($B$6:$B$13,MATCH($B$1,$A$6:$A$13,0))
```

One of the issues is that we don't know what or where your array is - it could be a range, a table, a named range, a hard-coded array, etc. Obviously, this answer will only apply to a range but you can adapt it for any other type of array. We also don't know what you've tried already, which is usually a requirement for a question before we answer it. That would have revealed what kind of array this is, for example.

You asked if it was a *tough nut to crack?* The answer is no, but the lack of details in your question sure has put a hard shell around that nut. And if you're after a really fast response, then you need to provide as much detail as you possibly can. It's probably true that *this is the best board to post to for answers*, but a good answer depends on a good question.

Comment: My array is same as what you have in the graphic "If you had a worksheet that looked as below:".  I thought index() was part of the answer.  BTW, I had to change your index order.  The last one should be first and subtract the first one (9-15 or 100-150=-50).  I thought I put enough details. 
 Anyway, thanks for your help--I really appreciate it!  I knew there was a way!